# Why would I need root access?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualhost, web, root

I'm not a backend guy, so please forgive such a simple question. I'm considering a php management service like [Cloudways](https://www.cloudways.com/en/), because I'd like dedicated droplets, but without the manual setup.

However, there is no root access. I will primarily be doing Wordpress sites, so I don't think I need it, but without really being a backend, code writing, web developer, why would one need root access? This service is similar but with root access: [RunCloud](https://runcloud.io/)

Just looking for examples when it might be needed. Don't want to sign up for something i'm limited by, but really have no idea why I would need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root or superuser access would mean that you're allowed to adjust any parameter of the system, to step outside the beaten path.

If you've tested the service and it allows you to do whatever you currently want, then you probably don't need root access. The question is, what happens when your needs happen to change, and you want to add something the service doesn't happen to support?

You'd have to figure out how hard is it for the service owners to compromise and either set things up for you differently, or allow you temporary or permanent access so you can do it yourself.

And if they tell you upfront that such customizations are impossible, then you have to pay attention to how hard is it for you to uproot yourself (pardon the turn of phrase) and move everything you have there to a different service.